# TypeError: f is undefined laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**this my controller**

```
if ($request->ajax())
  {
    $fields = Field::select(['id_lapangan','nama_lapangan','harga_sewa','gambar']);
    return Datatables::of($fields)
    // ->addColumn('action', function($field){
    //   return view('datatable._action', [
    //     'model' =>$field,
    //     'form_url'=>route('field.destroy', $field->id),
    //     'edit_url'=>route('field.edit',$field->id),
    //     'confirm_message'=>'yakin mau hapus'.$field->name .'?'
    //   ]);
    // })
    ->make(true);
  }

  $html = $htmlBuilder
    ->addColumn(['data'=>'id_lapangan','name'=>'id_lapangan','title'=>'No.'])
    ->addColumn(['data'=>'nama_lapangan','name'=>'nama_lapangan','title'=>'Nama Lapangan'])
    ->addColumn(['data'=>'harga_sewa','name'=>'harga_sewa','title'=>'Harga Sewa'])
    ->addColumn(['data'=>'gambar','name'=>'gambar','title'=>'Gambar'])
    ->addColumn(['data'=> 'action' , 'name' => 'action' , 'title' => '' ,
    'orderable' =>false , 'searchable' => false ]);

    return view('fields.index')->with(compact('html'));
```

**this my index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="active">Jadwal</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h2 class="panel-title">Lapangan</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              {!! $html->table(['class'=>'table-striped table-bordered']) !!}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
  {!! $html->scripts() !!}
@endsection
```

When I run on my browser, the data in the database does not appear,
and the eror is **TypeError: f is undefined**

Comment: Are you using variable `$f` some where in your blade file ?

Comment: no @SagarGautam

Comment: it is a javascript error not php ?

Comment: how to fix it bro? @AnarBayramov

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's because you've got 5 columns in your setup but for your ajax call you're only returning 4.

Either comment out:

```
->addColumn(['data'=> 'action' , 'name' => 'action' , 'title' => '' , 'orderable' =>false , 'searchable' => false ]);
```

Or add the logic back in for the ajax section.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i also corrected my scripts by adding @yield('scripts') in my app.blade

Comment: @DzikriSyarif If this has answered your question **please would you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.